# Ext Js 4 MVC Add Listener to Image in Grid Panel

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I would like to display an image in a grid panel and fire a click event when the user clicks on the image. I don't have a problem displaying an image. The problem I have is I am not sure how to add the listener to the image. Any help would be greatly appreciated? Really unsure what to do next. Thanks.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.people.List' ,{
extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
alias: 'widget.myList',
requires: [
    'MyApp.util.Globals',
    'MyApp.util.ImageTmpl'
],

id: 'myGrid',

title: 'All People',

initComponent: function() {

    var imagesUrl =/'+MyApp.util.Globals.projectName+'/'+MyApp.util.Globals.imageFolder;


    this.store = {
        fields: ['name', 'email'],
        data  : [
            {name: 'Ed',    email: 'ed@sencha.com', myVal: 1},
            {name: 'Tommy', email: 'tommy@sencha.com',myVal: 2}
        ]
    };

    this.columns = [
        {header: 'Name',  dataIndex: 'name',  flex: 1},
        {header: 'Email', dataIndex: 'email', flex: 1},
        {header: '', dataIndex: 'myVal',
            renderer: function() {
                return Ext.String.format('<img src="'+imagesUrl+'/edit.png" />');
            }
        },
        {header: '', dataIndex: 'myVal',
            renderer: function() {
                return '<img src="'+imagesUrl+'/book.png" alt="Lesson Study"/>';
            }
        },
        {header: '', dataIndex: 'myVal',
            renderer: function(){

                var imageTmpl = Ext.create('MyApp.util.ImageTmpl');

                console.log(imageTmpl);

                return imageTmpl;
            }
        }
    ];

    this.callParent(arguments);
}
```

});

Comment: If you want click on the image you'll have to give it and id and hook on that. It's not exactly MVC as a controller `control` method hook on components, not html elements. Alternatively you can hook on cell click event in your grid, but not sure this is what you after?

Comment: I would like to click on the image and have the image perform some function. For example:
click on delete image and run restful delete 
click on edit and have form window with edit pop up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your column defs to this format that does a click on the cell, which I think will work for you situation:

```
{
    header: '', dataIndex: 'myVal',
    renderer: function() {
        return Ext.String.format('<img src="'+imagesUrl+'/edit.png" />');
    },
    listeners: {
        click: function(){
            //action of the image here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Reimius. This works. It adds a listener to the whole column but that is fine for what my needs are. I guess this solution would not work if you needed the click functionality on multiple images in the same column.

Comment: There are ways to make it dependent on rows and images within the column, but I won't get in to how to do that because it is a little more complicated.  If you ever need that, ask another question and I'll work through it with you.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this code, bus something along these lines should work:

```
Ext.define('app.controller.myController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    init: function() {
        this.control({
            'people.List': {
               afterrender: function( aCmp ){
                    var me = this; 
                    var iImages = aCmp.getEl().select('img'); 

                    iImages.on('click', function( aEvent, aElement ){
                        me.onImageClick( aElement );
                    });

                }
            }   
        });
    },

    onImageClick: function( aElement ) {
        console.log('Image Clicked');
    }   
});
```

Comment: Thanks Izhaki for your response but when I try this it does not work. btw your code was close should be: 
iImages.on('click', function( aEvent, aElement ){
                        me.onImageClick( aElement );
                    });

                })